# caesar cipher problems in python

Tags: python

I have the following code which gives me error saying it cannot convert 'int' object to str implicitly. the if statements were used so if a letter in WORD is ascii 125 and i had to shift it by 5, I wanted the shift to goto ascii 32 and calculate. if any of the letters in word was less than ascii 32 shift, then shift to 32.

```
word=input("enter something to encrypt")
offset=int(input("Enter a number to shift it by"))
     for char in word:
        newword= ord(char)
        newword =newword+ chr(newword) + offset
        if newwword<32:
            result=result+95
        elif newword >126:
            result=result-95
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you wrote is a little convoluted I'm afraid. A couple points though:

- Your for loop should not be indented.
- The "result" you calculate in the if-statements is not being used anywhere. I'm not sure this is intentional?

The error you are getting is from this line:

```
newword =newword+ chr(newword) + offset
```

newword is an integer prior to this statement, because `ord(char)` returns an integer.

Calling `chr(newword` turns that into a character... but then you try to add the offset (which is an integer) to that character.

Perhaps what you meant to do on this line is something more like `newword = newword + chr(newword + offset)`

HOWEVER, this will not yield you a caesar cipher of "word" as you are overwriting your previously shifted characters with the new characters each time you do the assignment here -> `newword= ord(char)`

Overall, I would perhaps suggest the following changes to your code:

```
word=input("enter something to encrypt")
offset=int(input("Enter a number to shift it by"))
newword = ""
for char in word:
    newchar = ord(char)
    newchar = newchar + offset
    if newchar < 32:
        newchar = newchar + 95
    elif newchar > 126:
        newchar = newchar - 95
    newword = newword + chr(newchar)
print("Encrypted word: " + newword)
```

Comment: i had the result defined, i forgot to mention it here. thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1) You set newword every loop iteration, so you will never have the full result.

2) You compare the newword with an integer. You should maybe save the `ord` value, add the offset to it, compare that with 32 and 126, convert it back to a char using `chr`, then add it to the newword which you initialized with `""` outside the loop, and after the loop print the newword. The order of all these steps does matter!